# Does InDesign CS6 support XSLT2?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, adobe-indesign

I use InDesign CS5.5 now, and InDesign supports only XSLT 1.0 for import or export XML. Does anyone know if InDesign CS6 supports XSLT 2.0?

I want to ask this question directly on the Adobe's forum, but I can't sign in, it's very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a quick try and the result is ambiguous. I think InDesign will eat xslt2 to the condition you don't call xslt 2 functions. So the answer is more about it can accept xslt 2.0 files but only with 1.0 syntax :P

Unless I am wrong but upper-case function for example runs well on Oxygen but raise an error within InDesign.

Loic
http://www.loicaigon.com

Comment: Thank you! I think maybe InDesign 6 is as InDesign 5.5, we can't call XSLT 2 fonctions in XSL files. I will test it when I install InDesign 6.

Comment: I did tests, unfortunately InDesign CS6 doesn't support XSLT 2.0 syntax.